# Uploading image and insering data into database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data to the database and upload an image. The image name will be saved in the database and the image will be saved in **Images** folder creating random folder inside. But nothing is saved in the database.

HTML code

```
 <form action="news.php" method="post">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input type="text"  placeholder="Title" class="form-control" name="title" required><br/><br/>

                    <label>Description-1</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" name="desc1" required></textarea><br/><br/>

                    <label>Description-2</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" name="desc2"></textarea><br/><br/>

                    <label>Description-3</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" name="desc3"></textarea><br/><br/>

                    <label>Description-4</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" name="desc4"></textarea><br/><br/>

                    <label>Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="Image" id="ImageFile" class="form-control">

                    <br/><br/>
                    <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

php code

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {

$title = $_POST['title'];
$desc1 = $_POST['desc1'];
$desc2 = $_POST['desc2'];
$desc3 = $_POST['desc3'];
$desc4 = $_POST['desc4'];
$Image = $_POST['Image'];

$folder_path = 'Images/';

$imagename = basename($_FILES['Image']['name']);
$newname2 = $folder_path . $imagename;

if ((@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'], $newname2))) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_news(title,desc1,desc2,desc3,dessc4,image) VALUES('{$title}','{$desc1}','{$desc2}','{$desc3}','{$desc4}','{$imagename}')";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$con);
    if ($result) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Submiited Successfully')</script>";
    }
}
```

}

Please help!!!

Comment: stop using mysql_* driver its no longer supported and it is  deprecated and will be removed  in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your form tag

from

```
 <form action="news.php" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="news.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' >
```

you will need

> enctype='multipart/form-data

when ever you are dealing with **files**

for more reference

> see this link **[Form-data explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)**

Comment: should there be a close ' for  enctype='multipart/form-data ?

Comment: yes sorry my mistake i didnt closed it. please close it

Comment: enctype='multipart/form-data" was useful. I had also another mistake in my code I had entered <button type="button"> instead <button type="submit"> thanx :)